React Native Expo Stack
export default function RootLayout() {
    return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack initialRouteName="Welcome">

        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" options={{headerShown: false}} /> 

        <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen"  options={{headerShown: false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" options={{headerShown: false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

I want to make the Welcome.tsx the default view to be opened when the app is newly opened, please help me

I think you made a mistake with the question's tags. I think you meant the javascript tag and not the java tag.

Welcome to StackOverflow. You basically have half the solution. The code your provided is used to link the routename to its component but you have seemed to forgot to add the component like so.
<Stack.Screen name="Welcome" options={{headerShown: false}} component={Welcome} />

In your Welcome component, the code should be something like this
export const Welcome: FunctionComponent<NativeStackScreenProps<StackParamList, "Welcome">> = ({ navigation }) => {}

Note: This is just an example and it can be different on your project but it should be something like this.
